# Custom ASMX Could not create type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, asmx

I was trying to add my own WebService/asmx to SharePoint 2013.

and I got this wonderful error message

> Sorry, something went wrong
>    An error occurred during the processing of /_layouts/MyFolder/MyWS.asmx. 
>   Could not create type 'MyNamespace.MyClassName'.
>
> Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 93a3de9c-2213-3030-a6c5-f324a2c11743
>
> Date and Time: 1/11/2015 10:11:35 AM

BTW, it was working on SharePoint **2007** with the **same** method which I've also seen to be working [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95443/create-asmx-webservice-on-sharepoint-2013):

1. I've compiled my WebService Against .Net 4.0 (AnyCpu) to get *MSIL* DLL file.
2. Copied the files to SharePoint machine
3. Installed to GAC by using this:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe -I MyDllName.dll`
4. Tested that the Dll were successfully installed by using this:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe -L MyDllName`
5. I've also tried to write text-only asmx to test the GAC:

```
    <%@ WebService language="C#" class="TestMyAssembly" %>
```

`using System;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Web.Services;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  [WebService(Namespace = "http://test.com/Test")]
  public class TestMyAssembly : WebService
  {
      [WebMethod]
      public String TestAssembly()
      {

        Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.Load("FullAssemblyName1, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=118db1178ce8ee11, processorArchitecture=MSIL");


        Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.Load("FullAssemblyName2, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=22e5225e223b2240, processorArchitecture=MSIL");

        if (assembly1 != null && assembly2 != null)
        {   
            return "No exception so far...";
        }

        return "Something is wrong";
      }
  }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Project was broken in some way.

I've created new Web Project, copied all files to the new project, and all is working again.

Weirdest thing I've ever seen.