# SharePoint 2013 - How to query members/users of an Active Directory group?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, active-directory, ldap

I have written some JavaScript code to get all groups and their users with permissions to a SharePoint list. Beside SharePoint groups there are also AD groups with permissions.
The Problem is, that I can't query the users of AD groups. Afaik there is no solution to do this with JavaScript.
What is the best method to get the users of an AD Group? Do I need some Kind of web Service?
I need to get the AD Group users to my JavaScript code.

Sorry for my broken English and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using JSOM you can find out whether the user is a domain user or not.

But there is no JSOM method available to expand a domain group and find the users. If you want to stick with JavaScript then you should create a web service, that can give you the information.

Deploy the web service under SharePoint context and use AJAX for getting the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have some good examples for setting up that kind of web service? I have never set up a web Service.

Comment: Try this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95443/create-asmx-webservice-on-sharepoint-2013